# Java not giving Error!

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, odbc

Here is my code - i am simply checking my MySQL database connection.
**But first i have compiled and run the program successfully. but then i have commented the line Class.forName .**
Still when i compile it runs successfully, without any error.Why?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class FirstJbdc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection cn=null;
        try {
            //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded successfully");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:myDSN","root", "java");
            System.out.println("Database connected successfully....");
            System.out.println(cn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lovely: the answer is in the question // TODO: handle exception

Comment: FirstJdbc you mean.. :) I have an answer below. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java 1.6 can find JDBC driver even without using Class.forName.

Here is relevant part of [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> The `DriverManager` methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of `java.sql.Driver`. For example, to load the `my.sql.Driver` class, the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
> my.sql.Driver
> ```
>
> **Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName().** Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

Comment: Hey Peter - please can you point to the docs that detail this, been searching but can't find anything - cheers Nick.

Comment: Don't you have to put the JDBC driver in a special folder for this to work?

Comment: @pjp - would've thought you'd have to do something like putting the driver in a 'special folder'.  Otherwise you'd be trawling through every class checking for which ones implement java.sql.Driver. which is gonna suck.

Comment: @Nick: check out Javadoc for [DriverManager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) in JDK 1.6, especially part beginning with "The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism."

Comment: @Peter: cheers, that's a tick on my learnt something new today list :-)

Answer (score 8):

I throws an error, alright. It's just that the

```
catch (Exception e){
     // here the exception is instantiated, but nothing is done about it
}
```

clause silently swallows your exception.

Try a

```
System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
```

in the catch clause

Comment: Agree - it runs without (displaying) an error but it does not run successfully (doesn't print the last two lines). Never ever ever (...) catch 'Exception' without handling it ;)

Comment: @peter - can you give any link related to this!

Comment: @Pradyumna Dandwate: Maybe you can edit the question with your updated code. Not sure what you meant by "tried handling exception."

Comment: I updated my answer with relevant info and link to authoritative documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: this only applies to pre-JDBC 4.0 Drivers.**

JDBC drivers are meant to have a `static` section that registers them with the `java.sql.DriverManager` when the class is loaded, hence the `Class.forName(String)` is required.

It's detailed here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/drivermanager.html

Answer (score 0):

try {

```
     //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      System.out.println("Driver loaded successfully");
      cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:myDSN","root", "java");
      System.out.println("Database connected successfully....");
      System.out.println(cn);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // add the following statement
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If you add the statement inside the catch block, then compile and run, you should see the error message like-

[*Some Com*][*Some* Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Answer (score 0):

Without `Class.forName()`, the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver is not loaded. By JDBC specification, `getConnection()` returns null if no driver is found for the URL, no exception is thrown. So this is expected behavior.

Comment: Except if you're using JDBC 4.0 (Java 6), because there it's not necessary anymore to load the driver with Class.forName(...). See the JavaDoc of java.sql.DriverManager.

Comment: The JDBC-ODBC driver from Sun is so old. It doesn't know the new tricks.

Comment: Oh yes, it does. Check out META-INF/services/ava.sql.Driver file inside jre/lib/resources.jar -- it contains "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver", i.e. JDBC-ODBC driver from Sun! So it can be definitely used *without* Class.forName() on Java 6.

Comment: You are right. I forgot we use a customized version of the driver.